# Zero argument count in main()?

Tags: c++, windows-10, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I want to design an application that will run as GUI (wxWidgets) if there are zero arguments or parameters passed to `main()`.   I can't get rid of command line (console) feature because the application will be run from scripts.  The application will also be run from File Explorer or executed from a desktop icon.

This brought about the question:  Can the first argument of `main(int count, char ** parameters)` be zero?

Use Case 1:  In Windows 10, using File Explorer (or shortcuts), will the argument count be zero?

I know that the first parameter is the absolute name of the executable, when run in command window.

Environment:
Windows 10 command window or desktop icon or File Explorer
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019
wxWidgets

Comment: `count` will always be 1 or more.  the call to the program itself is the first argument.

Comment: Is that true for windowing systems?

Comment: In Linux, the `exec*` family of function can be used to make `argc` zero. Maybe something similar exists for Windows.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes.

Comment: It's specified that `argv[argc]` will always be a null-pointer. That's about it for the command-line arguments.

Comment: You can just leverage a program option for instance and if the `-gui` flag is used when launching the program then a GUI will launch.

Comment: And it shouldn't be too hard to test, no? :-)

Comment: At link time in Windows you must decide of the /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE or /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS and the entry points are different. `main` or `WinMain`. AFAIK there must be 2 different executables and maybe a script to decide which one to launch, if you really need this.

Comment: On Windows you'll have to make a console-less gui app, then use WinAPI to make/attach to a console.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on any behavior that requires `argc` to be less than 1.  That won't prevent you from basing your program's startup-behavior on the evaluation of `argc > 1`, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm going to make a GUI application.  If there is only one argument, the program will be in GUI mode, otherwise run silently (like it was built for console).

Comment: *windowing systems* and *Windows systems* are completely different things. Windows apps must have either console or GUI subsystem. If it's console you can't hide the terminal. GUI apps can spawn or attach to a new terminal if needed though. Anyway you can't have an app that act like both a console and a GUI version. You must use some tricks like [a \*.com file with the same name that spawns the GUI exe if called without parameters](https://superuser.com/a/1584299/241386)

Comment: Testing `argc` is not a way to have a program that can run in "GUI mode" or "console mode" - usually console programs have a `main()` entry point, and GUI programs have a `WinMain()` or similar.   Instead create two separate executables, one for GUI (with a `WinMain()` and creates suitable windows, etc) and one for console (with `main()` and does nothing with GUI).   Then create a third program that, based on *its* command line options selectively launch one of the other two (e.g. via `CreateProcess()`).